# Complexity in case of 2 while loops nested inside 1 while loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here is my code. I want to know how to calculate the time complexity of this very specific part of code. As per the rule, we need to calculate first inner 2 while loops and then add them and then multiply them with outer loop, but i am unable to figure out how to calculate them and then arrive to the answer.

```
 int start=first,end=last;
int mid= (first+last)/2;
int temp;
while(start<=end)
{
    while(a[start]<a[mid])
    {
        start=start+1;
    }
    while(a[end]>a[mid])
    {
        end=end-1;
    }
    if(start<=end)
    {
        temp=a[start];
        a[start]=a[end];
        a[end]=temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you have so far?

Comment: @Kenneyi only know about teh outer loop that is in terms of o(n) ..not able to understand the inner while loops. Would appreciate if you can help me out.

Comment: It comes down to counting. Some hints: Saying `n = end - first`, the first inner loop iterates `n/2` times, in the worst case scenario. The 2nd loop is basically the same, another `n/2` times. So the body of that outer loop comes down to `n/2 + n/2 = n`.

Comment: @Kenney so the body of outer loop is now n. and the outer loop itself is o(n), so on multiplying should not it be o(n^2). feel free to correct my concept of this if i am wrong

Comment: If the outer loop was `for ( i = 0; i < n; i ++)`, then yes, but the complexity lies in the fact that the inner loop modifies `start` and `end`. Try to visualize what is happening: `start` is only incremented, moved toward `end`, and `end` is decremented, moving toward `start`. So the difference between them becomes less. You might want to add some debug statements, and run it with a small input set to see it in action and get a feel for it, if that helps.

Comment: i have run it and understood how exactly this works, but i am very poor on calculating complexity part which you guys are too good. so i just want to understand the overall picture of calculating the complexity here. @Kenney

Answer (score 1):

This is `O(end - start)`.

> As per the rule, we need to calculate first inner 2 while loops and then add them and then multiply them with outer loop

There is no such rule. You need to take into account the total number of operations executed. Sometimes you do what you describe, but there is no such general rule.

Think about how often each element is accessed: `O(1)` times. The inner loops move `start` and `end` towards each other. The outer loop does not reset the inner loops, they continue where they left off the previous iteration. Since you do `O(1)` operations `O(end - start)` times, this is `O(end - start)`.

Comment: i got the o(end-start) but can you explain how the rest are o(1) operation. thanks much. while(a[mid]<a[end]) is a o(1) operator and not in terms of o(n) thanks. how to calculate/derive to this logic would be much helpful

Comment: Since you bumped: o(n) = n * o(1). See [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) and [Complexity Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) - it's not called complexity theory without reason... :-)

Comment: @icantcode the **entire execution** of `while(a[mid]<a[end])`, over the course of executing everything you posted once, will be `O(n)`. Sometimes it stops, but then the outer while continues it from where it left off on the next iteration.  The same for the other loop. `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`.